# impossible to build Xamarin.Android because Xamarin cannot find 'aapt.exe'

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use Xamarin in Visual Studio 16.3.6

I update visual studio but now I can't launch my app in Android because aapt.exe doesn't exist and when I run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat` nothing happen.

There is the full message error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(831,2): error XA5205: Cannot find `aapt.exe`.
Please install the Android SDK Build-tools package with the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat` program.
```

please help me, I try all older post but nothing works!

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked what you have installed in the SDK-manager?

Comment: I used the SDK Manager of android Studio... now I download the good build tools platform from sdk manager of Visual studio thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is looking in a different directory than where Android SDK manager is installing `aapt.exe`.

**Here's how I resolved the issue:**

Find `aapt.exe` on your local disk. Mine was located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\[version]\appt.exe
```

Then copy it to the directory that Visual Studio expects it to be in. For me, it was the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\
```